# a word (or a phrase) available when you just remembered something

Tags: phrase-requests

Imagine a situation as mentioned below.

You are talking with your friend, get satisfied, finish the talk, and open the door to go out, but suddenly you remember something to tell and say to him,

**"Oh,______"** (and your talk follows)

Is there a good word or a phrase to fit the blank other than "I just remembered"?

Thank you :)

Comment: I would say "Oh, by the way..." or "Oh, I forgot to tell you that...".

Comment: Kate's suggestions are good; also: *Oh, wait, I wanted to tell you* or *I wanted to talk to you about*.  And here's what my sixteen-year-old says: "BTW" (which stands for "by the way"), or "B T Dubs."  (I think "dubs" is short for the letter W.)

Answer (score 0):

I would likely just say either

“By the way,___”

or

“I almost/nearly forgot,___”

Answer (score -1):

**call to mind**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+to+mind) an idiom

> To cause one to think of or remember someone or something

As in:

*I do now **recall to mind** that time ...*

or just plain:

*I do now **recall** that time ...*

Comment: I don't know about other places, but in US English this would sound hopelessly out of place.